# How to verify the AES Key?

Tags: encryption, aes, keys

I'm Encrypting the data using AES-128 bit Encryption. I need to check whether the key is correct at the receiver side. How can I do that?

Suppose At the receiver The user is asked to enter the KEY for decrypting. As far as I know giving a wrong key generates some gibberish data. How can I prevent that and report back to user that the key provided is incorrect?

Comment: See https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/72658/how-do-i-detect-a-failed-aes-256-decryption-programmatically/79948#79948 for a working example based on AES-CBC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use AES 128 in GCM mode. This will generate a tag during encryption. Send that tag along with the ciphertext to receiver. If the receiver decrypts it with the wrong AES key, the sent tag and receiver computed tag will differ. Alert your user that the AES key is incorrect OR that the encrypted data is corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed use authenticated mode as DeepSpace101 suggested, but it has the disadvantage that if the data is large and the last part is e.g. missing that you may not see the difference between missing data and a wrong key being entered. It also slows down the verification as you need to verify all the data before the key can be compared (and no, this will not deter an attacker).

Another method is to use a KCV, most of time a block encrypt of zeros. This has the disadvantage that you don't want to use another block encrypt of zeros; so it is too dangerous in my opinion. You could also use a hash over the key as KCV, but that shows another issue (already present with the previous flawed try): if you reuse the key then the hash will be the same.

So all those things are sub-optimal at best. I'll suggest another one: use a KBKDF such as HKDF and provide a salt and a derived key value with the ciphertext. Use the salt and the input key as input of the KBKDF and calculate the derived value. Then compare it with the derived value stored with the ciphertext. Note that KDF's are irreversible so this should not give an attacker any advantage (but note that the key value *is* required in memory to do this).

Note that if you want to protect against active attackers you would need to include the salt & hash in the authenticated data (AAD data for authenticated / AEAD ciphers). Of course an active attacker may still let you believe that your data is at fault instead of the key if the key is reused by supplanting a previous salt/derived value - that cannot be avoided.

Comment: And an IV would still be required for the encryption of course, although you could reuse the salt or generate it with the KDF using another "label".

Answer (score 0):

You would do that by checking the integrity of the data decrypted. A simple way to do that is to add a magic value at the beginning of your data, and check if this magic value is effectively present when decrypting.

This magic value can for instance either be a constant, or a random value & the result of an operation on it (a hash function, or even just a binary NOT, etc.).

Comment: This is not often used anymore. We use MAC values or authenticated ciphers. You could e.g. replace the start of the ciphertext by a previous ciphertext and let the receiver think that the key is correct; the receiver would then try and decrypt the received ciphertext.

Comment: He never talked about authenticating the data, only the key.. As far as I understand the stated use-case, data is under his control and the user only submits the key. If you have a different threat model, you'll have to do otherwise indeed.

Comment: OK, but it does seem to indicate transport security is required ("...at the receiver..."). Please at least indicate the required strength of the "magic" value and that this is not secure against active attacks.

Comment: Note that I cannot remove my downvote without an edit of the answer; it becomes locked after a while.